# Netbeans and Eclipse side by side

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, netbeans

To this day I always use Eclipse for my Java developing stuff but in reason of some strange window handling improvements ;-) I think about a switch to Netbeans.

Based on the fact that other office mates still use Eclise I ask myself is it simply possible to use both IDEs side by side in the same project? What are side effects?

The related projects are all Maven based.

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/

Comment: @NimChimpsky does it allow to work with Eclipse projects?

Comment: you are using maven, therefore they are maven projects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your project is Maven based, then there should be no need to store IDE-specific files in your version control system (VCS). Consequently, there should be no impact if you choose to develop in one IDE over another, provided they understand POM files.

Each IDE will read the POM and generate it's own local files to cache state about the project. These will be different for each IDE, but since you don't commit those to VCS it doesn't matter. I suspect even if you did commit them, the paths and filenames are likely to differ anyway.

It's plausible some of your Eclipse friends will edit the POM to satisfy the stupid, stupid, stupid m2e connector system, but that should be ignored by other IDEs.

Comment: Thank you, so I give it a try ... and wait for the things that happen

Comment: @OkieOth Other things shouldn't happen. I work on a Maven project that I know is worked on by other people with different IDEs. Never any problems.